# Matlab findpeaks algorithm to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to apply the findpeaks method offered by Matlab on a Python project in order to achieve the same results.
On Internet, I retrieved many algorithms to find peaks in python but the best source I found out is the following one -> https://github.com/MonsieurV/py-findpeaks
However, this didn't solve my problem. 
In Matlab, I have this line of code:

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(a, 'MINPEAKDISTANCE', 72)
```

Hence, i tried out initially with the method offered by peakutils.indexes, in the following way :

```
locs= peakutils.indexes(y=a, thres=0, min_dist=72)
for val in locs:
    pks.append(a[val])
```

I am not really sure about 'thres=0' but in matlab the default value of threshold is 0, even if it seems intended in a different way with respect to peakutils.indexes.

The problem is that in the Matlab case I got 6635 peaks while in peakutils.indexes I got 6630 peaks (I am working on the signal 108 from MIT-BIH ARRHYTHMIA DATABASE offered by PhysioNet) . Moreover, some of them are not equals, that is in Matlab maybe one peak is located at 155 while in Python it is located at 158, and this, even if it is a small difference, causes problems in my algorithm.
I am actually working on this version of the pan and tompkins algorithm for ecg signal analysis-> https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45840-complete-pan-tompkins-implementation-ecg-qrs-detector

Comment: MATLAB is closed-source. There is no way to know all the details of this algorithm, and therefore there is no way of exactly recreating it in Python.

Comment: In continuation of Cris' comment, then there is one, pseudo, way and that is to use the API to MATLAB, https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html which allows you to call that exact function from Python.

Comment: @NickyMattsson thanks Nicky for your tip. Unfortunately, I omitted the fact that I need to run this Python code on an Android device, so I cannot use a Matlab engine to do this.

Comment: Generally speaking, you might also want to try the `scipy.signal.find_peaks`, see if it's any help

Answer (score 0):

some time ago I was facing the same problem and I found this function that worked just fine. It's a Matlab equivalent, try out and let us know if it worked for you. The code is not mine.

```
# %load ./../functions/detect_peaks.py
"""Detect peaks in data based on their amplitude and other features."""

from __future__ import division, print_function
import numpy as np

__author__ = "Marcos Duarte, https://github.com/demotu/BMC"
__version__ = "1.0.4"
__license__ = "MIT"


def detect_peaks(x, mph=None, mpd=1, threshold=0, edge='rising',
                 kpsh=False, valley=False, show=False, ax=None):

    """Detect peaks in data based on their amplitude and other features.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : 1D array_like
        data.
    mph : {None, number}, optional (default = None)
        detect peaks that are greater than minimum peak height.
    mpd : positive integer, optional (default = 1)
        detect peaks that are at least separated by minimum peak distance (in
        number of data).
    threshold : positive number, optional (default = 0)
        detect peaks (valleys) that are greater (smaller) than `threshold`
        in relation to their immediate neighbors.
    edge : {None, 'rising', 'falling', 'both'}, optional (default = 'rising')
        for a flat peak, keep only the rising edge ('rising'), only the
        falling edge ('falling'), both edges ('both'), or don't detect a
        flat peak (None).
    kpsh : bool, optional (default = False)
        keep peaks with same height even if they are closer than `mpd`.
    valley : bool, optional (default = False)
        if True (1), detect valleys (local minima) instead of peaks.
    show : bool, optional (default = False)
        if True (1), plot data in matplotlib figure.
    ax : a matplotlib.axes.Axes instance, optional (default = None).

    Returns
    -------
    ind : 1D array_like
        indeces of the peaks in `x`.

    Notes
    -----
    The detection of valleys instead of peaks is performed internally by simply
    negating the data: `ind_valleys = detect_peaks(-x)`

    The function can handle NaN's 

    See this IPython Notebook [1]_.

    References
    ----------
    .. [1] http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectPeaks.ipynb

    Examples
    --------
    >>> from detect_peaks import detect_peaks
    >>> x = np.random.randn(100)
    >>> x[60:81] = np.nan
    >>> # detect all peaks and plot data
    >>> ind = detect_peaks(x, show=True)
    >>> print(ind)

    >>> x = np.sin(2*np.pi*5*np.linspace(0, 1, 200)) + np.random.randn(200)/5
    >>> # set minimum peak height = 0 and minimum peak distance = 20
    >>> detect_peaks(x, mph=0, mpd=20, show=True)

    >>> x = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0]
    >>> # set minimum peak distance = 2
    >>> detect_peaks(x, mpd=2, show=True)

    >>> x = np.sin(2*np.pi*5*np.linspace(0, 1, 200)) + np.random.randn(200)/5
    >>> # detection of valleys instead of peaks
    >>> detect_peaks(x, mph=0, mpd=20, valley=True, show=True)

    >>> x = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    >>> # detect both edges
    >>> detect_peaks(x, edge='both', show=True)

    >>> x = [-2, 1, -2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0]
    >>> # set threshold = 2
    >>> detect_peaks(x, threshold = 2, show=True)
    """

    x = np.atleast_1d(x).astype('float64')
    if x.size < 3:
        return np.array([], dtype=int)
    if valley:
        x = -x
    # find indices of all peaks
    dx = x[1:] - x[:-1]
    # handle NaN's
    indnan = np.where(np.isnan(x))[0]
    if indnan.size:
        x[indnan] = np.inf
        dx[np.where(np.isnan(dx))[0]] = np.inf
    ine, ire, ife = np.array([[], [], []], dtype=int)
    if not edge:
        ine = np.where((np.hstack((dx, 0)) < 0) & (np.hstack((0, dx)) > 0))[0]
    else:
        if edge.lower() in ['rising', 'both']:
            ire = np.where((np.hstack((dx, 0)) <= 0) & (np.hstack((0, dx)) > 0))[0]
        if edge.lower() in ['falling', 'both']:
            ife = np.where((np.hstack((dx, 0)) < 0) & (np.hstack((0, dx)) >= 0))[0]
    ind = np.unique(np.hstack((ine, ire, ife)))
    # handle NaN's
    if ind.size and indnan.size:
        # NaN's and values close to NaN's cannot be peaks
        ind = ind[np.in1d(ind, np.unique(np.hstack((indnan, indnan-1, indnan+1))), invert=True)]
    # first and last values of x cannot be peaks
    if ind.size and ind[0] == 0:
        ind = ind[1:]
    if ind.size and ind[-1] == x.size-1:
        ind = ind[:-1]
    # remove peaks < minimum peak height
    if ind.size and mph is not None:
        ind = ind[x[ind] >= mph]
    # remove peaks - neighbors < threshold
    if ind.size and threshold > 0:
        dx = np.min(np.vstack([x[ind]-x[ind-1], x[ind]-x[ind+1]]), axis=0)
        ind = np.delete(ind, np.where(dx < threshold)[0])
    # detect small peaks closer than minimum peak distance
    if ind.size and mpd > 1:
        ind = ind[np.argsort(x[ind])][::-1]  # sort ind by peak height
        idel = np.zeros(ind.size, dtype=bool)
        for i in range(ind.size):
            if not idel[i]:
                # keep peaks with the same height if kpsh is True
                idel = idel | (ind >= ind[i] - mpd) & (ind <= ind[i] + mpd) \
                    & (x[ind[i]] > x[ind] if kpsh else True)
                idel[i] = 0  # Keep current peak
        # remove the small peaks and sort back the indices by their occurrence
        ind = np.sort(ind[~idel])

    if show:
        if indnan.size:
            x[indnan] = np.nan
        if valley:
            x = -x
        _plot(x, mph, mpd, threshold, edge, valley, ax, ind)

    return ind


def _plot(x, mph, mpd, threshold, edge, valley, ax, ind):
    """Plot results of the detect_peaks function, see its help."""
    try:
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    except ImportError:
        print('matplotlib is not available.')
    else:
        if ax is None:
            _, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 4))

        ax.plot(x, 'b', lw=1)
        if ind.size:
            label = 'valley' if valley else 'peak'
            label = label + 's' if ind.size > 1 else label
            ax.plot(ind, x[ind], '+', mfc=None, mec='r', mew=2, ms=8,
                    label='%d %s' % (ind.size, label))
            ax.legend(loc='best', framealpha=.5, numpoints=1)
        ax.set_xlim(-.02*x.size, x.size*1.02-1)
        ymin, ymax = x[np.isfinite(x)].min(), x[np.isfinite(x)].max()
        yrange = ymax - ymin if ymax > ymin else 1
        ax.set_ylim(ymin - 0.1*yrange, ymax + 0.1*yrange)
        ax.set_xlabel('Data #', fontsize=14)
        ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude', fontsize=14)
        mode = 'Valley detection' if valley else 'Peak detection'
        ax.set_title("%s (mph=%s, mpd=%d, threshold=%s, edge='%s')"
                     % (mode, str(mph), mpd, str(threshold), edge))
        # plt.grid()
        plt.show()
```

Comment: I already know this algorithm, it's the Duarte one but unfortunately, also this does not give me the same results. It actually founds 6698 peaks with the following combination :     detect_peaks(x=a, mpd=72) 
Do you think i should use some other configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your data without the for loop. It should find all the picks. The following should work:

```
peaks = peakutils.indexes(data, thres=10/max(data), min_dist=20)
```

where data is an array of `float64`. Maybe try to play with the threshold. You should also make sure the `min_dist` is smaller than peaks distance.

Good luck.